# SharePoint Users access token through SPO application client id and secret

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, access-token

Is there any way to get particular user's SPO access token through client id and secret of the custom application registered inside SPO site collection ? I do not want to show the consent screen to the user but still acquire the access token through client id and secret of the SPO app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We suggest you use app-only token to silently make requests. It's not possible to get other user's token without user interaction.

You may take a reference of :

- [client credentials flow](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow#get-a-token)
- [Resource Owner Password Credentials](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc)

BR

Comment: Thank you very much @Baker_Kong_MSFT for taking out time to answer my question. I was able to acquire app-only token through client credential flow. Just wanted to know if there is any OAuth flow or something else that i can use to acquire user's access token through client id and secret.

I have gone through a lot over the internet and did not find anything like that and your expert opinion helped me as well to conclude what i am looking is not supported at the moment.